# jQuery and Processing inside the same Canvas element?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, inline, processing

Is it possible to use both jQuery and [Processing](http://processingjs.org) *inside* the same canvas element?

It's easy enough to combine the two on the same page, but I am wondering if it's possible to place - for example - some jQuery UI draggable boxes *in* a canvas rendering some Processing code.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI is completely different from Processing, as it does not use `<canvas>`, but the DOM to create dialogs, draggables, et cetera.

So, no, it is impossible to use jQuery UI to draw on the canvas.

Comment: I don't mean draw on the canvas, but simply combine elements inline on the canvas..